# Generate clients from Swagger definition programmatically

Tags: python, swagger

I have a Swagger JSON definition file. I would like to generate Python client binding for it. I would like to generate it as part of my development cycle, i.e., every time the definition changes I can run a script locally to regenerate my client

I am aware of [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) and [Swagger Online Generators](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen#online-generators) but they are no satisfying my needs:

- both methods rely on an external service I need to call
- as result I am getting .zip file I need to unzip - that makes whole process more complex.

I remember times when I could generate Java client binding for SOAP service running Apache CXF locally. Is there something like that for Swagger? I've seen there's an option to clone the whole [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/) project, for all possible programming languages, but that seems like an overkill. Is there another option?

How companies are handling issue like mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator
You don't need to clone the whole repository, just download the JAR file and use it to generate the client/server.